# Project Euler #3 Get largest prime factor of a number

Tags: c++

So the Question was as follows:

**The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?**

I made a code for the question whose logic and algorithm seems correct but I can't seem to find the mistake, there's the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int x = 600851475143;
    for(long int i=x-1; x%i; --i);
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

*RE: Didn't know about the 'i' scope,  Teachers in my school didn't tell me =) [not blaming them]*

---

*RE: Thanx for all your responses, I got the answer. =)*

Comment: ...is that thing compiling? The variable you use in the loop does not exist outside, yet you try to print it.

Comment: @Riccardo It [doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/6G7Xkf).

Comment: Your program finds the largest factor of `x`. Why should it be prime? It may very well be, but it doesn’t need to. Check with `x = 8`.

Comment: Agree with Lumen... code is only checking whether number is prime or not...

Comment: @Lumen It finds the largest *proper* factor of `x`. The largest factor of `x` is `|x|` itself. :)

Comment: @sparite: if you got the answer, then mark the accepted one as such.

Comment: @Riccardo, I used the _information provided_ and made up my code, again, can't show that as it would _spoil_ the problem for any other person who _might_ stumble here.

Comment: @sparite you misunderstood me. Here on StackOverflow we do not label the question with [solved] tags or similar, we click on the "V" next to the answer which helped us the most in solving the issue. This will list your question as solved. You don't need to provide the final code you came up with.

Comment: long int is the same as long or int, to make it longer, use long long, int64_t or __int64

Comment: You can study other solutions by using the search box and sorting the result by most voted or relevance,  http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=600851475143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two small issues and one big issue:

- **Your `i` variable is out of scope for printing** - the scope of variables declared in the header of the statement ends with the statement itself. In this case, `i` is not visible after the semicolon, so you need to declare it outside the `for`
- **Your variables may not necessarily hold the values that you want to put into them** - `long` is allowed to be a 32-bit type, and on many platforms, it is. To make it at least a 64-bit type, change the declaration to `long long`.

Once you fix these problems, your code will compile. However, it will take ages to run because of the third, big, problem with your code: your algorithm is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

What about this instead? Just declare the `i` outsude of the for.

```
int main()
{
  long int x = 600851475143, i;
  for (i = x-1; x%i; --i);
  cout << i;
  return 0;
}
```

In your version `i` doesn't exist when you call `cout`.

```
int main()
{
    long int x = 600851475143;    /* here i doesn't exist */
    for(long int i=x-1; x%i; --i) /* here i is declared */ ;
    /* the for is closed by ; so the scope of i is already closed */
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

However, there are also other problems in your solution as pointed out by other answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

i is not accessible outside `for` loop.

```
long int i=0;
for(i= x-1;x%i;--i);
cout<<i<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

At least the following code compiles correctly and has no overflow problems:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long x = 600851475143, i;
 // ^^^^^^^^ Note the unsigned!
    for(i= x-1;x%i;--i);
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a bug:

if `x` is prime, you won't find the answer. `i` should start from the same value.

Comment: In that case, it will always output `x`.

Comment: If `i` starts from `x`, won't `x%i` evaluate to false and end the loop? what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please find one of the solution as below as the previous solution is running in infinite loop for me. Not quite sure though. But the below code works for me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_NUM 600851475143UL
unsigned long largest_prime_factor(unsigned long num)
{
    unsigned long c = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        for(unsigned long i = 2; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if(num % i == 0)
            {
                c = i;
                num = num / i;
                goto loop;
            }
        }
        break;
    loop:
        continue;
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%ld", largest_prime_factor(MAX_NUM));

    return 0;
}
```